# The sum of n terms of fractional expression is an integer when it should be a float

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, fractions, integer-division

In the following code why don't I get a valid result unless I put `term = 1.0/n` and not when `term = 1/n`. I have declared term as float, Shouldn't that be enough?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
     float sum = 0, term;
     int n, i;
     
     printf("enter the value of n:\n");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     term = 1.0 / n;
     for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     {  
        sum = term + sum; 
       
      }
     printf("Sum = %.3f\n", sum);   
     
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Because `1` is an `int` and so is `n` you end up with integer division. Using `1.0` results in floating point division.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Summing up `1/n`, `n` times will just give you 1. Do you want `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 .. + 1/n`?

Comment: I suspect you want to sum 1/i (or rather `1.0/i` in C).

Comment: The RHS of the expression `term = 1/n` is an int.  The type of the LHS is irrelevant when evaluating the RHS.

Answer (score 7):

> In the following code why don't I get a valid result unless I put `term = 1.0/n` and not when `term = 1/n`. I have declared `term` as `float`. Shouldn't that be enough?

Unfortunately no.

[ISO/IEC 9899:2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) §6.5.5 6 states:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.<sup>105)</sup> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a` [...]
>
> <sup>105)</sup> This is often called "truncation toward zero".

Translation: the result of this division of two integers is an integer.

Even if you assign it to a `float` or `double` variable it's not enough, it will be truncated before it's assigned, the solution is turn one of the operands in the fractional expression in a float or a double, like you did.